# How can I wrap static properties of a base class so that they return a sub class object?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static

Say I have code out there like this:

```
public class Base  // I cannot change this class
{
    public string Something { get; private set; }
    public string Otherthing { get; set; }

    public static Base StaticPreSet
    {
        get { return new Base { Something = "Some", Otherthing = "Other"}; }
    }

    public static Base StaticPreSet2
    {
        get { return new Base { Something = "Some 2", Otherthing = "Other 2"}; }
    }
}

public class SubClass : Base  // I can change this class all I want.
{
    public string MoreData { get; set; }

    // How can I wrap the PreSets here so that they return SubClass objects?
    // Something like this:
    public static SubClass MyWrappedPreset 
    {
       get
       {
          // Code here to call the base preset and then use it as the 
          // base of my SubClass instance.
       }
    }
}
```

What makes this complicated is the Something property.  It has a private setter.  So I can't set it in the subclass.  The only way it can be set is is via the preset properties.

**Is there a way to wrap the StaticPreSet property in my SubClass so that it will return an object of type SubClass?**

Comment: No, there isn't. They're not properties, and `static` members can't be overridden regardless...

Comment: I never understand these kind of questions.  They are however correctly identified with `// I cannot change this base class`.  That's a team problem, not an SO question.  Try programmers.se to sort these things out.

Comment: That was a bit negative perhaps, I do know you and you care about the code you write.  That's very awesome.  Don't know your team members.

Comment: @HansPassant - Alas, this is not an issue with my team.  (If so I would work to get a better design from them.)  This is an issue with a third party class that I am inheriting from.  I have already requested that they (Xceed) change it to make it more friendly (http://xceed.com/CS/forums/permalink/32355/32359/ShowThread.aspx#32359).  They have the request in the works, but that does not help me now.  Thus this question in hopes of a workaround.

Comment: Congratulations, again, you are ready to move beyond the confines of a 3rd party product.  Yes, they are a death-knell and will never respond to your requests.  You are, right now, entirely able and willing and capable to throw off the shackles and do it *your* way.  Don't need the SO crutch either.  Do it.

Answer (score 2):

> // I cannot change this base class.

Given that you can't change the base class, there is no way to cause it to change behavior (ie: return a different class at runtime).

If you could influence the design of the base class static methods, you *could* redesign it in a way to be flexible enough to provide this functionality.  However, without changing it, this won't work.

---

Edit in response to edit:

You could create a new static method that does what you are showing, like so:

```
public static SubClass MyWrappedPreset 
{
   get
   {
      // Code here to call the base preset and then use it as the 
      // base of my SubClass instance.
       Base baseInstance = Base.StaticPreSet;
       SubClass sc = new SubClass(baseInstance); // Create a new instance from your base class
       return sc;
   }
}
```

However, this provides a completely new, unrelated property - you'd have to access it via `SubClass.MyWrappedPreset`, not the `Base` class.

Comment: I am not trying to change the base class.  I just want to wrap it.  I updated my question to show what I am talking about.

Comment: Accessing it via the subclass is what I want... But I don't see how the constructor that you are using will work.  The `Something` property has a private setter.  So I can't just set all the values in a custom SubClass constructor.  And I don't see a way to do something like `this.base = baseInstance`.

Comment: @Vaccano THere is no "baseInstance" type of functionality, as they're completely separate objects.  If "Base" doesn't provide you any way at all to override or change "Something", you're kind of out of luck (other, than potentially, using reflection, but that'll only work in full trust)

Answer (score 0):

Static fields in a class "have nothing to do with it".
Basically, except access to private static fields, id doesn't matter in which class you put them - they behave the same.
If you inherit a class, and you declare another static field with the same name of a static field on the base class, you will simply 'hide' it. Example for you:

```
using System;
public class Base  // I cannot change this class
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public string Otherthing { get; set; }

    public static Base StaticPreSet
    {
        get { return new Base { Something = "Some", Otherthing = "Other"}; }
    }

    public static Base StaticPreSet2
    {
        get { return new Base { Something = "Some 2", Otherthing = "Other 2"}; }
    }
}

public class SubClass : Base  // I can change this class all I want.
{
    public string MoreData { get; set; }

    public static SubClass StaticPreSet2
    { 
        get { return new SubClass { Something = "inherited", Otherthing=""}; }
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(SubClass.StaticPreSet2.Something);
    }
}
```

Will write "inherited".